# TabHost.setCurrentTab(index) work for first time

Tags: android

I created TabActivity having two tabs with two activities.
one is login tab another is welcome tab.

user should not go welcome tab unless login successfully.if he tries to select welcome tab he throws to login tab.i use tabHost.setcurrenttab(index).

But when i click direct welcome tab it works fine for first time. When i again click tab rapidly it opens welcome tab.

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.product_list);
            SharedPreferences mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            username = mPreference.getBoolean("valid", false);
            Toast.makeText(this, "In Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           //login sucessful            
           tabActivity.switchTab(0);
     }
```

on onResume, i repeat the same code.

Comment: repeat the same code? there you just need to setCurrentTab to login page if user is not logged in,no need of other statements.

Comment: Question is still not very clear.

Comment: it works for first time but if i repeatedly click second tab it opens

Comment: jeet it should throw user from second tab if he not login thats it.i used tabhost.setcurrenttab for it but it not work it work sometimes not always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your TabActivity. This is to prevent user to switch tab if he is not logged in.(I have no time to check it now,please let me know if any issue is there with the code):

```
SharedPreferences mPreference;
....onCreate(){

    ...

    mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

                username = mPreference.getBoolean("valid", false);
                if(user is logged in){
                     tabHost.setcurrenttab(0);//welcome page
                }
                else{
                     tabHost.setcurrenttab(1);//login page
                }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome.Hiral It Worked For Me.Thank You.I searching From Yesterday.You Rocked!!!!!